# Stackdriver - monitor multiple JMX

Tags: jmx, stackdriver

I'm trying to configure google stackdriver to monitor multiple JVM instances on same machine by using this plugin: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/jvm
I created two  block with different ServiceURL ports (for different JMXs) and different InstancePrefix ("jvm" and "jvm2") like it described here: https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:GenericJMX
But I still don't see second jvm in metrics-explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this kind of configuration is not currently supported by the Stackdriver monitoring agent. The suggested workaround is to use [Custom Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/).

Comment: Thank you, i've already found this way but forgot to notice it.